# How to pass substring of byte array using index in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to transmit one APDU and I get back the response. I want to check the last two bytes by an API which will log the comparison.

```
byte[] response = Transmit(apdu);

//response here comes will be 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 
//response.Length will be 5


byte[] expectedResponse = { 0x03, 0x04 };

int index = (response.Length)-2;

Log.CheckLastTwoBytes(response[index],expectedResponse);

//The declaration of CheckLastTwoBytes is 
//public static void CheckLastTwoBytes(byte[] Response, byte[] ExpResp)
```

This is an error of invalid arguments. How can I pass the last 2 bytes to APIs?

Comment: Actually I wanted to know, if it is possible to pass substring using index without using temporary array. (like how we can do in C)

Comment: Not in C#, sorry to say.

Comment: ArraySegment is a way to reference a slice of an array without making a copy of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new ArraySegment<byte>(response, response.Length - 2, 2).Array
```

EDIT: nevermind this, apparently `.Array` just returns the original entire array and not the slice. You would have to modify your other method to accept ArraySegment instead of byte[]

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[2];
Array.Copy(response, response.Length-2, newArray, 2);
Log.CheckLastTwoBytes(newArray,expectedResponse);
```

Comment: Or... you could just have two assignments? It's just two bytes. No need for actually Array.Copy...

Comment: yeah, Array.Copy can be replaced with 2 assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of `response[index]` is `byte` (**not** `byte[]`), it's not surprising that you'd get that error.

If `Log.CheckLastTwoBytes` really does check just the last two bytes of its `Response` parameter, then you should just pass `response`:

```
   Log.CheckLastTwoBytes(response, expectedResponse)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a subarray just like that, no...

First solution, obvious one:

```
var tmp = new byte[] { response[response.Length - 2],
                       response[response.Length - 1] };

Log.CheckLastTwoBytes(tmp, expectedResponse);
```

Or, you could do this:

```
response[0] = response[response.Length - 2];
response[1] = response[response.Length - 1];

Log.CheckLastTwoBytes(response, expectedResponse);
```

It might be that this function doesn't check for exact lengths, etc, so you could just put the last two bytes as the first two, if you don't care about destroying the data.

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, you can use linq:

```
byte[] lastTwoBytes = response.Skip(response.Length-2).Take(2).ToArray();
```