# Byte Array Substring

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays

I am trying to return a substring of a byte array.

(another application is pushing data into my database, where files have a prepended GUID attached to it. I want to remove this GUID, when giving the file back to the user)

```
if (bytes.Length > 38)
            {
                string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                returnBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s.Substring(38));
            }
```

Is it possible to do this without Text Encoding? Maybe via Array.Copy() ?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618231/how-to-pass-substring-of-byte-array-using-index-in-c

Comment: Do you know exact position of your guid in the byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use `Buffer.BlockCopy`

```
    Byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[bytes.Length - 16];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 16, fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
```

BTW Guid is normally 16 bytes length, 38 is string length

Comment: This does work, as it truncates my byteArray, but unfortunatelly my pdf is not readable. Seems to be a problem with how many bytes to skip.

Answer (score 1):

For the part of returning a substring of an array, you can use `ArraySegment<T>`.
Refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx)